Can't open Jupyter Notebook in cmd
>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I tried to open the Jupyter notebook through cmd after downloading notebook using the command
pip install notebook


maybe it didn't create batch for jupyter and you have to run python -m jupyter notebook
